# Como automatizar a execução de scripts Python no Google Colab? Sheduler

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, ipython-notebook, scheduler

Desenvolvi um script em python para automatizar requisições e integração de dados com o BigQuery. Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de executar este script automaticamente em uma rotina de segunda a sexta, sempre à meia noite, ou algo do tipo.

1. Alguém sabe informar se é possível criar essa rotina?
2. Vou precisar subir o script em alguma maquina virtual (cloud)?
3. O Google Colab é capaz de executar o código sem que meu computador esteja ligado?

Fico muito grato!

Answer (score -1):

Sim, é possível que seu colab seja executado após você encerrar a seção (desligar seu computador). Porém, esse recurso está disponível apenas na versão PRO (paga).

*"Usuários sem assinatura não devem contar com a execução em segundo plano. Ela será interrompida quando a interação dos usuários acabar, e a VM será excluída logo depois"*.

Para maiores informações acesse esse link:
https://colab.research.google.com/signup/pricing?utm_source=dialog&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=settings_page